# Conventional Programming: How do you return two Types of primitive ('int and 'string') from "get" method?

Tags: java, methods, getter, getter-setter, primitive-types

Trying to print out `age` and `name` of an Object using "get" method. However, my get method `return` type is string:

```
public String displayProfile() {
    System.out.print(getName() + getAge());
```

Hence the error:

```
This method must return a result of type String
```

Here is my main method: if user enters '2' from the "menu" ***where (2 == profile)*** the program should display user's `name` and `age`.

*Side note: To select "friends" from menu, user will enter '3' (3 = friends).*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

// Initializing Objects
People zac = new People();
 zac.setName("zac");
 zac.setAge(18);

 People lisa = new  People();
 lisa.setName("lisa");
 lisa.setAge(19);

 // Zac be-friend LISA
 zac.addFriend("lisa");

    openApp();
    if(optionSelected == 3)
    {
       System.out.println(zac.getFriend());

       else if (optionSelected == 2) {
           System.out.println(zac.displayProfile());
        }
     }
       }
```

**Being new to programming, I want to develop good programming practices, hence with this in mind; how would you display `age` and `name` of different type [int = age and string = name] from one method like i.e. `public String displayProfile()` OR is this completely wrong? Then what are the alternatives?**

**Additionally**:

My `getName()` method:

```
// GET NAME 
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
```

My `setName()` method:

```
 // SET NAME 
public  void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
```

My `getAge()` method:

```
// GET AGE

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
```

My `setAge()` method:

```
// SET AGE

    public void setAge(int age) {
        age = this.age;
        }
```

Comment: Don't confuse performing output with returning a value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.format()` with format specifiers (`%s, %d, %f...`)

```
public static String displayProfile()
{
    return String.format("%s %d", "StackOverflow", 6);
}
```

**Note** the `return` statement. It's totally different than `System.out.print(...)`

Also, the body of `setAge()` method, should look like:

```
this.age = age;
```

since you want to assign the `age` passed as parameter to the member `this.age`