# How to Print out two objects using String.format()

Tags: java, methods, type-conversion, primitive-types, string.format

I'm a little confused. Previously I posted a question: [Conventional Programming: How do you return two Types of primitive ('int and 'string') from "get" method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794804/conventional-programming-how-do-you-return-two-types-of-primitive-int-and-st)

The answer it got was to use use `String.format() with format specifiers (%s, %d, %f...)`.

And although the answer was a bit confusing, I understand that %f means to convert (?)

But how do you print out `age` and `name` using this method. My attempt:

```
// DISPLAY Person name and age

public String displayProfile() {
    return String.format(%fgetAge(), %fgetName())

        }
```

Main method from which *above* method gets executed:

```
 if (optionSelected == 2) {
           System.out.println(zac.displayProfile());
       }
```

I'm all over the place with this, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:
As requested,I'm posting the get and set methods used with the String.format() method. Because although I'm not getting any errors after the correcting the String.format method, it not printing out the 'name' and 'age' after I return the getAge() and GetName() from String.format(). What is the mistake I'm making any ideas?**

```
 // SET NAME 
public  void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }

// GET NAME 
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}   


// SET AGE

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
    }

// GET AGE

public int getAge() {
    return this.age;
}
```

Comment: Hey Guys! So I made the alterations and not getting any errors. However, I doesn't print out "name" or even "age" when the main method is executed: if (optionSelected == 2) {
           System.out.println(zac.displayProfile());
       }

Answer (score 2):

The format specifiers and functions would need to be separate so the specifiers are in the string and the functions need to be called after the string:

```
public String displayProfile() {
    return String.format("%d, %s", getAge(), getName());
    }
```

Comment: Note: Be sure to confirm that the `getAge()` and `getName()` functions are returning the correct types.

Comment: I made the alterations and not getting any errors. However, I doesn't print out "name" or even "age" when the main method is executed: if (optionSelected == 2) { System.out.println(zac.displayProfile()); }. Any suggestions?

Comment: It doesn't print out the values or just the words name and age? If its the latter then just change `"%d, %s"` to `"Age: %f, Name: %s"`

Comment: Hey @jomahoney, thanks for your reply. Actually it doesn't print either the value or the words 'name' and 'age'. Although I'm WANT to print out the values of age and name. Any suggestions?

Comment: I noticed yours and my code snippets were missing the `;`. Without seeing all the code, I can't see an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make that:

```
public String displayProfile() {
  return String.format("%d %s", getAge(), getName())

}
```

The format method takes several arguments, the first is always the string to be formatted. All other are the variables which replace the placeholders in the first string. So what you are basically doing here is telling java to print you a string (`"%d %s"`) which has two placeholders (one for integers, one for strings) separated by a single space character. Then you supply the values for your placeholders, from left to right in the same order.

Also I'd strongly suggest that you start browsing through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ or some other tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format()` as:

```
public String displayProfile() {
    return String.format("Age: %f, Name: %s", getAge(), getName());
}
```

Where `%f` stands for a *floating-point* type and `%s` for *String* type. I don't think you will need floating points for representing `Age`. I'd rather use *int* and use `%d` in order to format.

You can read further on formatting [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
   String   birinchison =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Birinchi sonni kiriti");
        String   ikkinchiSon =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Birinchi sonni kiriti");
        int raqam1= Integer.parseInt(birinchison);
        int raqam2 =Integer.parseInt(ikkinchiSon);
        int yigindi = raqam1+raqam2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null ,"ularni yigindisi" + yigindi , "Sarlavha" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    enter code here
```